# Within EU we can stay in another EU country for 3 months, when does the period reset?

Tags: schengen, international-travel, europe, legal, eu-citizens

Would it count if I left the country, made a U-turn and came back? Or rented a hotel for a night? When can I go back and keep living in that country after leaving when my 90 days is done?

Are there some requirements or regulations? I only could find information on Schengen visa, which is not the case if you yourself are EU citizen.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ but AFAIK there is no limit on how long you can stay. There is just a requirement to register with the authorities beyond 3 months in some countries.

Answer (score 2):

The details depends on the country.

Some countries have no rule at all, some have intergrated it into their own, national, registration laws.

In Germany, **everyone** must register their residence when moving in to a new address. When a EU citizen does this the first time, this 3 months condition is considered to be fulfilled. Nothing more needs to be done.

Without knowing which country you are presently are living in, no usefull information can be given other that **border hopping** is not a solution.

Comment: There is much room for confusion and ambiguity, though.  Suppose an EU citizen wants to spend two weeks in each of ten German cities as a tourist.  The person is not establishing residence in Germany and has no basis to register with any city, but plans to spend nearly five months in Germany.

Comment: @phoog The **Freizügigkeitsgesetz/EU** does not forsee an actual requirement to register after 3 months, it only states that after 3 months that the legal requirements can be checked: [Allgemeine Verwaltungsvorschrift zum Freizügigkeitsgesetz/EU](https://www.verwaltungsvorschriften-im-internet.de/bsvwvbund_03022016_MI12100972.htm) ***5.2.1** The immigration authorities **can** demand that the legal requirements for residence be substantiated by providing information and submitting the necessary evidence from both Union citizens and ...  However, this is only permitted three months after entry*

Comment: @phoog It is unlikly that any hotel registration would be passed on to the immigration authorities, so such a requests unlikly to happen. The EU citizen only needs to react upon request.

Answer (score 2):

> When can I go back and keep living in that country after leaving when my 90 days is done?

There is no strict 90-day limit, nor a strict 3-month limit.  There is a right to reside for up to three months with almost no conditions and a right to reside for more than three months that is subject to somewhat greater conditions.

This means that a country can impose penalities for exceeding three months without meeting the greater conditions, but there is no requirement to impose any penalities.  Thus, the existence of any such penalities depends on which country you're in.  It could also depend on your circumstances.

In general, if you have the means to support yourself, you can stay as long as you want, and if you fail to comply with any registration requirement imposed by the country where you're staying, you can be fined.  Whatever penalty is imposed must be "proportional" and cannot include expulsion simply for failing to register.

Whether a temporary absence from the country would reset the three-month clock would likely depend on circumstances.  If you have a fixed place of residence, most legal decision makers would probably find that a short trip out of the country does not interrupt your residence.  If you're traveling around from place to place, a short trip abroad is more likely to help, but it's far from guaranteed.